# add an activity indicator to show when the app is busy in jquery mobile, phonegap / cordova

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, activity-indicator

I want to display an activity indicator when my app is busy on ios. So far I haven't been able to get it working.

I have tried using:

```
navigator.notification.activityStart();
```

Which seems like it's not supported in most recent versions of Phonegap/Cordova.

Does anyone know how to get this working with Phonegap and Jquery mobile?

Answer (score 0):

I was accidentally removed in 1.5 but will be back in 1.6. If you just grab the code from the 1.4.1 JS version and paste it into the 1.5 version it should just work as well.

Comment: Hi Simon, I have tried adding the the following code from 1.4.1.js but it uses phonegap    /**
 * Start spinning the activity indicator on the statusbar
 */
Notification.prototype.activityStart = function() {
    PhoneGap.exec(null, null, "Notification", "activityStart", ["Busy","Please wait..."]);
};

/**
 * Stop spinning the activity indicator on the statusbar, if it's currently spinning
 */
Notification.prototype.activityStop = function() {
    PhoneGap.exec(null, null, "Notification", "activityStop", []);
};

Comment: It should be fine but you can change the instances of PhoneGap to "cordova"

Comment: Was this ever restored on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  Looks like the iOS notification stuff was once a part of the main distribution but now it's a plugin that you have to add to your app.  I found the plugin here:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/NotificationEx

There is a README there with accurate install instructions for recent versions of PhoneGap / Cordova.  I got it working pretty quick once I found the plugin.

Comment: This repository has been deprecated.